# colorful.core.ColorfulError: the color "default" is unknown. Use a color in your color palette (by default: X11 rgb.txt)

Tags: python, django

I installed the `colorful` into my django project and I added it to installed_apps in `settings.py`

I added an `RGBColorField` to my modal.

When I do `python manage.py makemigrations`
I get the following error: `colorful.core.ColorfulError: the color "default" is unknown. Use a color in your color palette (by default: X11 rgb.txt)`

my modals.py

```
  from __future__ import unicode_literals
  from colorful.fields import RGBColorField
  from django.db import models

  class Party(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    color = RGBColorField(default="#0000")
```

I also tried with     `color = RGBColorField("#0000")` and  `color = RGBColorField()`  and `color = RGBColorField(default="#000")` with valid color tags but always the same error

Any help? any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trials, I finally resolved it.

The problem was that I have installed colorful with `pip install colorful`.

I used `pip install django-colorful` instead and everything worked great

Answer (score 0):

`#0000` is not a valid color tag.

```
color = RGBColorField(default="#000")
```

or

```
color1 = RGBColorField(colors=['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF'])

color2 = RGBColorField(colors='#333,#ff00FF')
```